# Animate UITableView height change

Tags: uitableview, uiviewanimation

I'm using the code below to animate UITableView height change in response to keyboard appearing/disappearing.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
CGRect tableFrame = self.messagesTableView.frame;

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
    tableFrame.size.height -= kKeyboardHeightPortrait;
} else {
    tableFrame.size.height -= kKeyboardHeightLandscape;
}

self.messagesTableView.frame = tableFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It's working as expected except for one thing, as soon as the animation starts, the cells in the upper half of the table view disappear.

Before animation starts:
[image]

After animation starts:
[image]

It's also worth mentioning that the table view is an instance of [UIBubbleTableView](https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your issue, but could not. In any case I have just submitted extended example of UIBubbleTableView into github which does the thing you are trying to do and everything seems good so far, take a look at the latest commit (https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView/commit/bc0dc5b151241c4ae476c894e23800156e9709a8)

If you still have questions feel free to add issues into github tracker or contact me to provide the source you think does not work for investigation. Email is available in github profile.

Comment: It turned out that the cause of the problem was a call to scrollToRowAtIndexPath after the animation block. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you never initialize those cells.

Comment: The cells are already initialised and added to the screen (the upper part of the table view in the first picture).

Comment: maybe call some kind of reload void?